# IOException vs. TimeoutException

Tags: c#, .net

Assuming you design a `System.IO.Stream` extension `MyStream` whose `Read` method can time out, which exception type would you rather throw:

- `System.IO.IOException` (as e.g. `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`) or
- `System.TimeoutException` (as e.g. `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`) or
- something else?

Comment: Personally I would mimic what existing .NET classes were doing; both options are arguably valid so go with the one that people may already be familiar with.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I think that's tamberg's point - there are multiple exceptions in the BCL that, at first glance, seem appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If the exception is that the `Stream` is going to "time out", then I would personally use `TimeoutException`.  This is very clear, and very appropriate if that is the underlying cause.

`IOException` is used by `NetworkStream`, but has a different meaning.  In this case, it's typically because the underlying socket has closed, which prevents the read/write from occurring...

Answer (score 1):

You use a [`TimeoutException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx); it most accurately conveys what actually happened.

The [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx) is more of a general-purpose exception; if something happened while reading the underlying backing store for the [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) for which there's not a specific exception then I'd expect an `IOException`.

`TimeoutException` is the standard here, so go with that.

Answer (score 0):

When a network stream times out, `IOException.InnerException` is a `SocketException`, and `IOException.InnerException.SocketErrorCode` is `SocketError.TimedOut`.

I wish it just threw a TimeoutException so I don't have to test for this bizarre condition.